# Powershell request works but python request does not

Tags: python, powershell, request

Powershell request:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://u.gg/api" `
-Method "POST" `
-Headers @{
"method"="POST"
  "authority"="u.gg"
  "scheme"="https"
  "path"="/api"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`" Not;A Brand`";v=`"99`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"91`", `"Chromium`";v=`"91`""
  "accept"="*/*"
  "authorization"=""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
  "x-is-ssr"="false"
  "origin"="https://u.gg"
  "sec-fetch-site"="same-origin"
  "sec-fetch-mode"="cors"
  "sec-fetch-dest"="empty"
  "referer"="https://u.gg/lol/profile/euw1/kdowww/overview"
  "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "accept-language"="fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
  "cookie"="_ga=GA1.2.968995068.1654506355; __qca=P0-1614171154-1654506352586; __stripe_mid=981900fd-2bcc-4d93-b083-a525e3fcc138cd4504; euconsent-v2=CPcW4gAPcW4gAAKAoAENCYCsAP_AAH_AAAQAI6td_X__bX9j-_5_aft0eY1P9_r37uQzDhfNs-8F3L_W_LwXw2E7NF36pq4KmR4Eu1LBIQNlHMHUDUmwaokVrzHsak2cpyNKJ7JEknMZO2dYGF9Pn1lDuYKY7_5_9_bx2D-t_9_-39T378Xf3_dp_2_--vCfV599jfn9fV_789KP9__9v-_8__________3_4IwAEmGpcQBdmWODJoGEUKIEYVhIVQKACCgGFogsAHBwU7KwCXUELABAKkIwIgQYgowYBAAIJAEhEAEgBYIBEARAIAAQAIgEIACJgEFgBYGAQAAgGhYgBQACBIQZEBEcpgQFQJBQS2ViCUFehphAHWeAFAojIqABEkgIJAQEhYOAYAkBLxZIGmKF8gBGCFAA.f_gAAAAAAAAA; addtl_consent=1~39.4.3.9.6.9.13.6.4.15.9.5.2.7.4.1.7.1.3.2.10.3.5.4.21.4.6.9.7.10.2.9.2.18.7.6.14.5.20.6.5.1.3.1.11.29.4.14.4.5.3.10.6.2.9.6.6.4.5.4.4.29.4.5.3.1.6.2.2.17.1.17.10.9.1.8.6.2.8.3.4.142.4.8.42.15.1.14.3.1.8.10.25.3.7.25.5.18.9.7.41.2.4.18.21.3.4.2.7.6.5.2.14.18.7.3.2.2.8.20.8.8.6.3.10.4.20.2.13.4.6.4.11.1.3.22.16.2.6.8.2.4.11.6.5.33.11.8.1.10.28.12.1.3.21.2.7.6.1.9.30.17.4.9.15.8.7.3.6.6.7.2.4.1.7.12.13.22.13.2.12.2.10.5.15.2.4.9.4.5.4.7.13.5.15.4.13.4.14.8.2.15.2.5.5.1.2.2.1.2.14.7.4.8.2.9.10.18.12.13.2.18.1.1.3.1.1.9.25.4.1.19.8.4.5.3.5.4.8.4.2.2.2.14.2.13.4.2.6.9.6.3.4.3.5.2.3.6.10.11.6.3.16.3.11.3.1.2.3.9.19.11.15.3.10.7.6.4.3.4.6.3.3.3.3.1.1.1.6.11.3.1.1.11.6.1.10.5.2.6.3.2.2.4.3.2.2.7.15.7.12.2.1.3.3.4.5.4.3.2.2.4.1.3.1.1.1.2.9.1.6.9.1.5.2.1.7.2.8.11.1.3.1.1.2.1.3.2.6.1.12.5.3.1.3.1.1.2.2.7.7.1.4.1.2.6.1.2.1.1.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.1.8.1.7.4.3.2.1.3.5.3.9.6.1.15.10.28.1.2.2.12.3.4.1.6.3.4.7.1.3.1.1.3.1.5.3.1.3.2.2.1.1.4.2.1.2.1.2.2.2.4.2.1.2.2.2.4.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.2.1.2.1.7.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.3.2.1.1.8.1.1.1.5.2.1.6.5.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.2.1.1.4.3.1.2.2.1.2.1.2.3.1.1.2.4.1.1.1.5.1.3.6.3.1.5.2.3.4.1.2.3.1.4.2.1.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.11.1.3.1.1.2.2.5.2.3.3.5.1.1.1.4.2.1.1.2.5.1.9.4.1.1.3.1.7.1.4.5.1.7.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.4.2.1.12.1.1.3.1.2.2.3.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.3.1.5.1.2.4.3.8.2.2.9.7.2.3.2.1.4.6.1.1.6.1.1; __gads=ID=155ad9ec62b0acb9:T=1658227217:S=ALNI_MaeFZXBlFL9tJe3GZXxSXGInGrsfw; _gid=GA1.2.1818596812.1659252934; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=670979120346242; amp_7eca13=_n3A1d2FoGmrY7VRfDDdX_...1g9bqrjr3.1g9bqrjr3.0.0.0; _gat_UA-99072557-3=1; __stripe_sid=ea466266-921a-4b17-bda2-01d09295360fff7f07"
} `
-ContentType "application/json" `
-Body "{`"operationName`":`"FetchMatchSummaries`",`"variables`":{`"regionId`":`"euw1`",`"summonerName`":`"kdowww`",`"queueType`":[420],`"duoName`":`"`",`"role`":[],`"seasonIds`":[18],`"championId`":[]},`"query`":`"query FetchMatchSummaries(`$championId: [Int], `$page: Int, `$queueType: [Int], `$duoName: String, `$regionId: String!, `$role: [Int], `$seasonIds: [Int]!, `$summonerName: String!) {\n  fetchPlayerMatchSummaries(\n    championId: `$championId\n    page: `$page\n    queueType: `$queueType\n    duoName: `$duoName\n    regionId: `$regionId\n    role: `$role\n    seasonIds: `$seasonIds\n    summonerName: `$summonerName\n  ) {\n    finishedMatchSummaries\n    totalNumMatches\n    matchSummaries {\n      assists\n      championId\n      cs\n      damage\n      deaths\n      gold\n      items\n      jungleCs\n      killParticipation\n      kills\n      level\n      matchCreationTime\n      matchDuration\n      matchId\n      maximumKillStreak\n      primaryStyle\n      queueType\n      regionId\n      role\n      runes\n      subStyle\n      summonerName\n      summonerSpells\n      psHardCarry\n      psTeamPlay\n      lpInfo {\n        lp\n        placement\n        promoProgress\n        promoTarget\n        promotedTo {\n          tier\n          rank\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamA {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamB {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      version\n      visionScore\n      win\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n`"}"
```

My python request:

```
resp = req.post(f'https://u.gg/api',
        data={
            "operationName":"FetchMatchSummaries",
            "variables":
                {
                    "regionId":"euw1",
                    "summonerName":"kdowww",
                    "queueType":[420],
                    "duoName":"",
                    "role":[],
                    "seasonIds":[18],
                    "championId":[]
                },
                "query":"query FetchMatchSummaries($championId: [Int], $page: Int, $queueType: [Int], $duoName: String, $regionId: String!, $role: [Int], $seasonIds: [Int]!, $summonerName: String!) {\n  fetchPlayerMatchSummaries(\n    championId: $championId\n    page: $page\n    queueType: $queueType\n    duoName: $duoName\n    regionId: $regionId\n    role: $role\n    seasonIds: $seasonIds\n    summonerName: $summonerName\n  ) {\n    finishedMatchSummaries\n    totalNumMatches\n    matchSummaries {\n      assists\n      championId\n      cs\n      damage\n      deaths\n      gold\n      items\n      jungleCs\n      killParticipation\n      kills\n      level\n      matchCreationTime\n      matchDuration\n      matchId\n      maximumKillStreak\n      primaryStyle\n      queueType\n      regionId\n      role\n      runes\n      subStyle\n      summonerName\n      summonerSpells\n      psHardCarry\n      psTeamPlay\n      lpInfo {\n        lp\n        placement\n        promoProgress\n        promoTarget\n        promotedTo {\n          tier\n          rank\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamA {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamB {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      version\n      visionScore\n      win\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
                
            },
        headers={
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "method":"POST",
                    "authority":"u.gg",
                    "scheme":"https",
                    "path":"/api",      
                    #   "sec-ch-ua"="" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"",
                    "accept":"*/*",
                    "authorization":"",
                    "sec-ch-ua-mobile":"?0",
                    "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36",
                    "x-is-ssr":"false",
                    "origin":"https://u.gg",
                    "sec-fetch-site":"same-origin",
                    "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
                    "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
                    "referer":"https://u.gg/lol/profile/euw1/kdowww/overview",
                    "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
                    "accept-language":"fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
                    "cookie":"_ga=GA1.2.968995068.1654506355; __qca=P0-1614171154-1654506352586; __stripe_mid=981900fd-2bcc-4d93-b083-a525e3fcc138cd4504; euconsent-v2=CPcW4gAPcW4gAAKAoAENCYCsAP_AAH_AAAQAI6td_X__bX9j-_5_aft0eY1P9_r37uQzDhfNs-8F3L_W_LwXw2E7NF36pq4KmR4Eu1LBIQNlHMHUDUmwaokVrzHsak2cpyNKJ7JEknMZO2dYGF9Pn1lDuYKY7_5_9_bx2D-t_9_-39T378Xf3_dp_2_--vCfV599jfn9fV_789KP9__9v-_8__________3_4IwAEmGpcQBdmWODJoGEUKIEYVhIVQKACCgGFogsAHBwU7KwCXUELABAKkIwIgQYgowYBAAIJAEhEAEgBYIBEARAIAAQAIgEIACJgEFgBYGAQAAgGhYgBQACBIQZEBEcpgQFQJBQS2ViCUFehphAHWeAFAojIqABEkgIJAQEhYOAYAkBLxZIGmKF8gBGCFAA.f_gAAAAAAAAA; addtl_consent=1~39.4.3.9.6.9.13.6.4.15.9.5.2.7.4.1.7.1.3.2.10.3.5.4.21.4.6.9.7.10.2.9.2.18.7.6.14.5.20.6.5.1.3.1.11.29.4.14.4.5.3.10.6.2.9.6.6.4.5.4.4.29.4.5.3.1.6.2.2.17.1.17.10.9.1.8.6.2.8.3.4.142.4.8.42.15.1.14.3.1.8.10.25.3.7.25.5.18.9.7.41.2.4.18.21.3.4.2.7.6.5.2.14.18.7.3.2.2.8.20.8.8.6.3.10.4.20.2.13.4.6.4.11.1.3.22.16.2.6.8.2.4.11.6.5.33.11.8.1.10.28.12.1.3.21.2.7.6.1.9.30.17.4.9.15.8.7.3.6.6.7.2.4.1.7.12.13.22.13.2.12.2.10.5.15.2.4.9.4.5.4.7.13.5.15.4.13.4.14.8.2.15.2.5.5.1.2.2.1.2.14.7.4.8.2.9.10.18.12.13.2.18.1.1.3.1.1.9.25.4.1.19.8.4.5.3.5.4.8.4.2.2.2.14.2.13.4.2.6.9.6.3.4.3.5.2.3.6.10.11.6.3.16.3.11.3.1.2.3.9.19.11.15.3.10.7.6.4.3.4.6.3.3.3.3.1.1.1.6.11.3.1.1.11.6.1.10.5.2.6.3.2.2.4.3.2.2.7.15.7.12.2.1.3.3.4.5.4.3.2.2.4.1.3.1.1.1.2.9.1.6.9.1.5.2.1.7.2.8.11.1.3.1.1.2.1.3.2.6.1.12.5.3.1.3.1.1.2.2.7.7.1.4.1.2.6.1.2.1.1.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.1.8.1.7.4.3.2.1.3.5.3.9.6.1.15.10.28.1.2.2.12.3.4.1.6.3.4.7.1.3.1.1.3.1.5.3.1.3.2.2.1.1.4.2.1.2.1.2.2.2.4.2.1.2.2.2.4.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.2.1.2.1.7.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.3.2.1.1.8.1.1.1.5.2.1.6.5.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.2.1.1.4.3.1.2.2.1.2.1.2.3.1.1.2.4.1.1.1.5.1.3.6.3.1.5.2.3.4.1.2.3.1.4.2.1.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.11.1.3.1.1.2.2.5.2.3.3.5.1.1.1.4.2.1.1.2.5.1.9.4.1.1.3.1.7.1.4.5.1.7.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.4.2.1.12.1.1.3.1.2.2.3.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.3.1.5.1.2.4.3.8.2.2.9.7.2.3.2.1.4.6.1.1.6.1.1; __gads=ID=155ad9ec62b0acb9:T=1658227217:S=ALNI_MaeFZXBlFL9tJe3GZXxSXGInGrsfw; _gid=GA1.2.1818596812.1659252934; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=670979120346242; amp_7eca13=_n3A1d2FoGmrY7VRfDDdX_...1g9bqrjr3.1g9bqrjr3.0.0.0; _gat_UA-99072557-3=1; __stripe_sid=ea466266-921a-4b17-bda2-01d09295360fff7f07"
                    }
        )
```

The powershell request works but I get an "Internal Server error" 400 response with the python one. I think it is the query or the variables in the data that may cause it.

well now stackoverflow does not want me to post my question bcs "it looks like you posted mainly code, pls give more info"

FOUND THE SOLUTION:

```
def get_last_games(summoner, region='euw'):
    cookies = {
        '_ga': 'GA1.2.968995068.1654506355',
        '__qca': 'P0-1614171154-1654506352586',
        '__stripe_mid': '981900fd-2bcc-4d93-b083-a525e3fcc138cd4504',
        'euconsent-v2': 'CPcW4gAPcW4gAAKAoAENCYCsAP_AAH_AAAQAI6td_X__bX9j-_5_aft0eY1P9_r37uQzDhfNs-8F3L_W_LwXw2E7NF36pq4KmR4Eu1LBIQNlHMHUDUmwaokVrzHsak2cpyNKJ7JEknMZO2dYGF9Pn1lDuYKY7_5_9_bx2D-t_9_-39T378Xf3_dp_2_--vCfV599jfn9fV_789KP9__9v-_8__________3_4IwAEmGpcQBdmWODJoGEUKIEYVhIVQKACCgGFogsAHBwU7KwCXUELABAKkIwIgQYgowYBAAIJAEhEAEgBYIBEARAIAAQAIgEIACJgEFgBYGAQAAgGhYgBQACBIQZEBEcpgQFQJBQS2ViCUFehphAHWeAFAojIqABEkgIJAQEhYOAYAkBLxZIGmKF8gBGCFAA.f_gAAAAAAAAA',
        'addtl_consent': '1~39.4.3.9.6.9.13.6.4.15.9.5.2.7.4.1.7.1.3.2.10.3.5.4.21.4.6.9.7.10.2.9.2.18.7.6.14.5.20.6.5.1.3.1.11.29.4.14.4.5.3.10.6.2.9.6.6.4.5.4.4.29.4.5.3.1.6.2.2.17.1.17.10.9.1.8.6.2.8.3.4.142.4.8.42.15.1.14.3.1.8.10.25.3.7.25.5.18.9.7.41.2.4.18.21.3.4.2.7.6.5.2.14.18.7.3.2.2.8.20.8.8.6.3.10.4.20.2.13.4.6.4.11.1.3.22.16.2.6.8.2.4.11.6.5.33.11.8.1.10.28.12.1.3.21.2.7.6.1.9.30.17.4.9.15.8.7.3.6.6.7.2.4.1.7.12.13.22.13.2.12.2.10.5.15.2.4.9.4.5.4.7.13.5.15.4.13.4.14.8.2.15.2.5.5.1.2.2.1.2.14.7.4.8.2.9.10.18.12.13.2.18.1.1.3.1.1.9.25.4.1.19.8.4.5.3.5.4.8.4.2.2.2.14.2.13.4.2.6.9.6.3.4.3.5.2.3.6.10.11.6.3.16.3.11.3.1.2.3.9.19.11.15.3.10.7.6.4.3.4.6.3.3.3.3.1.1.1.6.11.3.1.1.11.6.1.10.5.2.6.3.2.2.4.3.2.2.7.15.7.12.2.1.3.3.4.5.4.3.2.2.4.1.3.1.1.1.2.9.1.6.9.1.5.2.1.7.2.8.11.1.3.1.1.2.1.3.2.6.1.12.5.3.1.3.1.1.2.2.7.7.1.4.1.2.6.1.2.1.1.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.1.8.1.7.4.3.2.1.3.5.3.9.6.1.15.10.28.1.2.2.12.3.4.1.6.3.4.7.1.3.1.1.3.1.5.3.1.3.2.2.1.1.4.2.1.2.1.2.2.2.4.2.1.2.2.2.4.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.2.1.2.1.7.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.3.2.1.1.8.1.1.1.5.2.1.6.5.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.2.1.1.4.3.1.2.2.1.2.1.2.3.1.1.2.4.1.1.1.5.1.3.6.3.1.5.2.3.4.1.2.3.1.4.2.1.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.11.1.3.1.1.2.2.5.2.3.3.5.1.1.1.4.2.1.1.2.5.1.9.4.1.1.3.1.7.1.4.5.1.7.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.4.2.1.12.1.1.3.1.2.2.3.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.3.1.5.1.2.4.3.8.2.2.9.7.2.3.2.1.4.6.1.1.6.1.1',
        '__gads': 'ID=155ad9ec62b0acb9:T=1658227217:S=ALNI_MaeFZXBlFL9tJe3GZXxSXGInGrsfw',
        '_gid': 'GA1.2.1818596812.1659252934',
        '_pbjs_userid_consent_data': '670979120346242',
        'amp_7eca13': '_n3A1d2FoGmrY7VRfDDdX_...1g9bqrjr3.1g9bqrjr3.0.0.0',
        '_gat_UA-99072557-3': '1',
        '__stripe_sid': 'ea466266-921a-4b17-bda2-01d09295360fff7f07',
    }

    headers = {
        'authority': 'u.gg',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36',
        'x-is-ssr': 'false',
        # Already added when you pass json=
        # 'content-type': 'application/json',
        'origin': 'https://u.gg',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://u.gg/lol/profile/euw1/kdowww/overview',
        'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
        # 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.968995068.1654506355; __qca=P0-1614171154-1654506352586; __stripe_mid=981900fd-2bcc-4d93-b083-a525e3fcc138cd4504; euconsent-v2=CPcW4gAPcW4gAAKAoAENCYCsAP_AAH_AAAQAI6td_X__bX9j-_5_aft0eY1P9_r37uQzDhfNs-8F3L_W_LwXw2E7NF36pq4KmR4Eu1LBIQNlHMHUDUmwaokVrzHsak2cpyNKJ7JEknMZO2dYGF9Pn1lDuYKY7_5_9_bx2D-t_9_-39T378Xf3_dp_2_--vCfV599jfn9fV_789KP9__9v-_8__________3_4IwAEmGpcQBdmWODJoGEUKIEYVhIVQKACCgGFogsAHBwU7KwCXUELABAKkIwIgQYgowYBAAIJAEhEAEgBYIBEARAIAAQAIgEIACJgEFgBYGAQAAgGhYgBQACBIQZEBEcpgQFQJBQS2ViCUFehphAHWeAFAojIqABEkgIJAQEhYOAYAkBLxZIGmKF8gBGCFAA.f_gAAAAAAAAA; addtl_consent=1~39.4.3.9.6.9.13.6.4.15.9.5.2.7.4.1.7.1.3.2.10.3.5.4.21.4.6.9.7.10.2.9.2.18.7.6.14.5.20.6.5.1.3.1.11.29.4.14.4.5.3.10.6.2.9.6.6.4.5.4.4.29.4.5.3.1.6.2.2.17.1.17.10.9.1.8.6.2.8.3.4.142.4.8.42.15.1.14.3.1.8.10.25.3.7.25.5.18.9.7.41.2.4.18.21.3.4.2.7.6.5.2.14.18.7.3.2.2.8.20.8.8.6.3.10.4.20.2.13.4.6.4.11.1.3.22.16.2.6.8.2.4.11.6.5.33.11.8.1.10.28.12.1.3.21.2.7.6.1.9.30.17.4.9.15.8.7.3.6.6.7.2.4.1.7.12.13.22.13.2.12.2.10.5.15.2.4.9.4.5.4.7.13.5.15.4.13.4.14.8.2.15.2.5.5.1.2.2.1.2.14.7.4.8.2.9.10.18.12.13.2.18.1.1.3.1.1.9.25.4.1.19.8.4.5.3.5.4.8.4.2.2.2.14.2.13.4.2.6.9.6.3.4.3.5.2.3.6.10.11.6.3.16.3.11.3.1.2.3.9.19.11.15.3.10.7.6.4.3.4.6.3.3.3.3.1.1.1.6.11.3.1.1.11.6.1.10.5.2.6.3.2.2.4.3.2.2.7.15.7.12.2.1.3.3.4.5.4.3.2.2.4.1.3.1.1.1.2.9.1.6.9.1.5.2.1.7.2.8.11.1.3.1.1.2.1.3.2.6.1.12.5.3.1.3.1.1.2.2.7.7.1.4.1.2.6.1.2.1.1.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.1.8.1.7.4.3.2.1.3.5.3.9.6.1.15.10.28.1.2.2.12.3.4.1.6.3.4.7.1.3.1.1.3.1.5.3.1.3.2.2.1.1.4.2.1.2.1.2.2.2.4.2.1.2.2.2.4.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.2.2.1.1.2.1.2.1.7.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.1.3.2.1.1.8.1.1.1.5.2.1.6.5.1.1.1.1.1.2.2.3.1.1.4.1.1.2.2.1.1.4.3.1.2.2.1.2.1.2.3.1.1.2.4.1.1.1.5.1.3.6.3.1.5.2.3.4.1.2.3.1.4.2.1.2.2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.11.1.3.1.1.2.2.5.2.3.3.5.1.1.1.4.2.1.1.2.5.1.9.4.1.1.3.1.7.1.4.5.1.7.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.1.4.2.1.12.1.1.3.1.2.2.3.1.2.1.1.1.2.1.1.2.1.1.1.1.2.1.3.1.5.1.2.4.3.8.2.2.9.7.2.3.2.1.4.6.1.1.6.1.1; __gads=ID=155ad9ec62b0acb9:T=1658227217:S=ALNI_MaeFZXBlFL9tJe3GZXxSXGInGrsfw; _gid=GA1.2.1818596812.1659252934; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=670979120346242; amp_7eca13=_n3A1d2FoGmrY7VRfDDdX_...1g9bqrjr3.1g9bqrjr3.0.0.0; _gat_UA-99072557-3=1; __stripe_sid=ea466266-921a-4b17-bda2-01d09295360fff7f07',
    }

    json_data = {
        'operationName': 'FetchMatchSummaries',
        'variables': {
            'regionId': 'euw1',
            'summonerName': 'kdowww',
            'queueType': [
                420,
            ],
            'duoName': '',
            'role': [],
            'seasonIds': [
                18,
            ],
            'championId': [],
        },
        'query': 'query FetchMatchSummaries($championId: [Int], $page: Int, $queueType: [Int], $duoName: String, $regionId: String!, $role: [Int], $seasonIds: [Int]!, $summonerName: String!) {\n  fetchPlayerMatchSummaries(\n    championId: $championId\n    page: $page\n    queueType: $queueType\n    duoName: $duoName\n    regionId: $regionId\n    role: $role\n    seasonIds: $seasonIds\n    summonerName: $summonerName\n  ) {\n    finishedMatchSummaries\n    totalNumMatches\n    matchSummaries {\n      assists\n      championId\n      cs\n      damage\n      deaths\n      gold\n      items\n      jungleCs\n      killParticipation\n      kills\n      level\n      matchCreationTime\n      matchDuration\n      matchId\n      maximumKillStreak\n      primaryStyle\n      queueType\n      regionId\n      role\n      runes\n      subStyle\n      summonerName\n      summonerSpells\n      psHardCarry\n      psTeamPlay\n      lpInfo {\n        lp\n        placement\n        promoProgress\n        promoTarget\n        promotedTo {\n          tier\n          rank\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamA {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      teamB {\n        championId\n        summonerName\n        teamId\n        role\n        hardCarry\n        teamplay\n        __typename\n      }\n      version\n      visionScore\n      win\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n',
    }

    resp = req.post('https://u.gg/api', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)

    return resp.text
```

when you have this issue just copy the request as curl (powershell) and paste it there https://curlconverter.com/#python

Comment: The two bodies are not the same.  The powershell has `"operationName":"FetchMatchSummaries"` as a top-level item in the data, but the python code has it as a sub-item underneath `"variables"`.

Comment: changed as you said but I get the same error... @JohnGordon